# Restore variable in tensorflow without specifying its shape

Tags: python, tensorflow

I can restore a variable this way in tensorflow:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    var = tf.Variable([6, 7])
    tf.train.Saver({'name': pvdm_train}).restore(sess, 'model.ckpt'))
```

But how do I restore it if the shape is unknown? This is quite helpful when I want to just load a variable and use it to say perform classification.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by loading the meta graph from the checkpoint:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(
        'my-save-dir/my-model-10000.meta')
    saver.restore(sess, 'my-save-dir/my-model-10000')
```

This requires you to use `write_meta_graph=True` when saving the model - that's the default though.

You can find more about this [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/meta_graph).